# Twitter Bootstrap: overflow of btn-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of `button`s inside a `div` with fixed width and auto height. I want the contained buttons to shift to the next line once they overflow the container div.

Here's my code:

```
<div class='btn-group' style='width:100px; height:auto;'>
  <button class='btn'>Hello</button>
  <button class='btn'>Hello</button>
  <button class='btn'>Hello</button>
  <button class='btn'>Hello</button>
  <button class='btn'>Hello</button>
  <button class='btn'>Hello</button>
  <button class='btn'>Hello</button>
</div>
```

The buttons get out of the group. Doing a `<br />` helps but I'd prefer if there is a more direct solution since I am inserting buttons programatically. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this, it defeats the purpose of a button group?

Comment: The buttons go out of the bound of the outer box that messes with my page style

Comment: Splitting a button group won't look very nice.

Comment: I posted an answer, I'm just not sure that is what you want to roll with but, if it works for you.

Comment: It shifts to next line to me - http://jsfiddle.net/bUyEf/

Comment: @Win my question title as well as tags clearly state that this has to work with Twitter Bootstrap. I know it would work otherwise.

Comment: @Win I believe that was the intent of the question.

Comment: @mihsathe - My example used twitter bootstrap 3.0.0. Look like it was fixed in new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `whitespace` property on `.btn-group`

```
.btn-group{
    white-space: normal;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/k9XCj/

Comment: Yup. This works. I agree that this kinda looks not-so-smooth but I think it serves my purpose for now.